# Open Hardware Monitor fan control via standard app GUI

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-speed

I have downloaded and I am using the Open Hardware Monitor app to display the temperatures of my Intel i7 core in my Sony Vaio VPCF1 laptop ( using windows 7 ). 
But the downlaoded app GUI does not display any fan speed information or any function for actually adjusting a fan speed. There is no sub-menu under the name of the motherboard "**VAIO**" in the displayed menu list (GUI).
The documentation for this app on its web site is very poor and provides very little information about how to use the app or its standard functions

How can I display and / or adjust fan speed just using its standard GUI ( not by writing custom code to do so) ?